# Can't connect via SSH from some systems

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

We have a setup of 2 computing servers, and I can connect via SSH to each one of them just fine.

From Windows:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUser> ssh user@server1 -vvv
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\MyUser/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\MyUser/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for server1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "server1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to server1 [10.68.18.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
```

And then some more, and the connection works.

When I want to connect to this server from the other computing server, I instead get:

```
(base) user@server2:~$ ssh roth@server1 -vvv
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "server1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to server1 [10.68.18.78] port 22.
^C
```

It hangs infinitely at connecting to server1, until I cancel the ssh connection. I tried disabling the firewall on both systems, that did not help though, and now I am out of ideas what to look for in resolving this issue.

The systems are ubuntu20.04 (server2) and ubuntu18.04 (server1).

If I want to connect to server2 from server1, that works just fine.

Comment: "infinitely" — for how long you tried to wait? Also, what happens in logs when all of this happens?

Comment: In what logs? I've waited for 5 minutes at least, and considering from the Windows Powershell it works instantly (basically), I don't see how I can't call that infinitely

Comment: I believe 10.x.x.x IP addresses are private network addresses, so if you're trying to connect from outside the network I think you'd need to use the public IP and have NAT forwarding set up. Please update your question with info about how the network is facing the internet and e.g. `iptables -L` output. But I only just started learning this stuff myself so I probably cannot help much, and if I misunderstood your question please ignore this comment.

Comment: I mean SSH server logs. You didnd't show any. The comparison with "almost instantly" is unnecessary. Firewall could easily produce such an experience; problems with DNS also usual source of login delays (SSH server by default queries DNS and waits for the reply or the timeout, which might be rather long). Also don't forget an extreme: the packet capture; you'll see at least what it has an activity on the network when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: So, this is an internal network. When I use the powershell to connect, I am doing so through a VPN. The DNS is resolved correctly, the IP address matches. I did disable the firewall on both systems to make sure that was not the issue. In the sshd log I see no mention of the connection even happening

Comment: Which means, the connection doesn't reach the server. A routing issue is very possible, especially in an environment where also VPN is used. Check routing on all involved systems.

Comment: Well, I can ping the server just fine? Thought the same, but doesn't the working ping mean it finds the route?